# Generate every possible intervals of integers

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, integer, intervals

Despite my researches, I have found no solution to my issue. Thank you for your help !

Let a and b, two integers. I want to generate all sub intervals of integers no matter their lengths between this two integers.

For example, let a=2 and b=5, the result I tried to obtained is:

```
[
 [[2],[3],[4],[5]
 [[2,5]],
 [[2],[3,5]],
 [[2],[3,4],[5]],
 [[2],[3],[4,5]],
 [[2,3],[4,5]],
 [[2,3],[4],[5]],
 [[2,4],[5]]
]
```

Thank you for your help,

Best regards !

Comment: If single value list is acceptable, why not `[[2], [3], [4], [5]]` included?

Comment: Yes ! I forget this one ! Thank you !

Comment: Please edit the question and add missing values.

Comment: You might be missing [[2,3], [4]], [[2], [3,4]] etc

Comment: @yuvrajzohan What about 5 ?

Comment: @yuvrajzohan No. OP requires list of ranges that ends with 5 (or the last element of the given list.)

Comment: @Guillaume, Ah! now I understand your question. So each array must have both 2 and 5 and rest of the elements in interval are optional?

Comment: @yuvrajzohan Yes ! That's it ! Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a function that yields intervals from numbers closest to `a` (which is `a` itself) to `b`, and then recursively yields the intervals from `a + 1` to `b`:

```
def intervals(a, b):
    if a > b:
        yield []
    for i in range(a, b + 1):
        for interval in intervals(i + 1, b):
            yield [[a] if a == i else [a, i], *interval]
```

so that:

```
list(intervals(2, 5))
```

returns:

```
[[[2], [3], [4], [5]],
 [[2], [3], [4, 5]],
 [[2], [3, 4], [5]],
 [[2], [3, 5]],
 [[2, 3], [4], [5]],
 [[2, 3], [4, 5]],
 [[2, 4], [5]],
 [[2, 5]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a method that does what you asked for. It's not very beatiful to look at, but it does the job.

```
def subIntervals(a,b):
    outputList = [[[a]]]
    for n in range(a+1, b+1):
        newOutputList = []
        for e in outputList:
            newOutputList.append(e + [[n]])
            newOutputList.append(e[:-1] + [[e[-1][0], n]])
        outputList = newOutputList
    return outputList
```

I will add an explanation if needed.